# Java Synchronizing objects, wait and notify

Tags: java, synchronized

I have a program that rolls dice, and uses a new thread to loop through in order to update the image and repaint.  Here is my code:

```
public int roll()
{
  new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        synchronized(o) {
          o.notify();
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            image = randomImage();
            repaint();
            try {
              Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex) {
              System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ).start();

  synchronized(o) {
    try {
      o.wait();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
    }
  }
  return rolled;
}
```

In my other class, I have:

```
int rolled = dicePanel.roll();
label.setText("Rolled a + rolled");
```

The problem is that with the current code with synchronization, the dice images do not animate, but do return the correct int rolled.  Without the synchronized code, the images will animate but the roll method will return a 0 as the int because it does not let the other thread finish.

Is there any way to have the image code loop through and repaint each time, but wait until the thread has finished to return the int rolled?

Comment: First comment - I can't see much purpose in calling `o.notify()` when you've just obtained a lock on `o` and plan to keep it for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an overly complicated solution. You should certainly perform your dice rolling / image updating in thread other than the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), but you needn't split that task into two separate threads.

Just have one thread that fiddles with your dice images then when it's finished doing that, it can set the chosen dice value in your label (and presumably in your image too).

Comment: Setting the label after the dice images are looped through worked, not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the `o.notify();` to the end of the `run()` method. Btw. using `notifyAll()` should be preferred. Or you may find useful the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object pattern. Here is an article about it http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Or if you are developing Swing application look to [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). However, SwingWorker is probably overkill for this task.

Wait&notify is quite low level api and there are many good abstraction in Java to work with concurrency.

Comment: SwingWorker looks interesting for future, more complex programs, thanks